# how can i display checkboxes from read data in database in view using form in zend 1.11

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, checkbox, zend-form

**read form data from database and dispaly in checkbox in view using form in zend 1.11**

1. i create a roleController.php in zend controller

   ```
   <?php

   class RoleController extends Zend_Controller_Action
   {

       public function init()
       {
           /* Initialize action controller here */
       // do some thing    

       }
       public function indexAction()
       {
           // action body
       // do some thing    
       }               
   }            
   ?>
   ```

**i also create role.php in form folder in zend 1.11**

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Setting extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */

        $this->setMethod('post');


        $this->addElement('checkbox', 'role[]', array(
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim')
        ));


        $this->addElement('button', 'Save', array(
            'value'    => 'Submit',
            'type'     => 'Submit',
            'class'    => 'btn blue'
        ));
        // Add the submit button


    $this->role[]->removeDecorator('Label');
        $this->role[]->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $this->Save->removeDecorator('Label');
        $this->Save->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
        $this->Save->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    }


}

?>
```

**role.php in db-table folder in model**

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Role extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'role_tbl';
    protected $_primary  = 'role_id';


}
```

**in view role.phtml**

```
<label><?php 
echo $this->form->getElement('role[]'); ?>Index</label>
```

**my question is that how can i read data form database and display checkboxes in view using form**

[image]

my role_table is

```
+-----------------------+------------------+
|   role_id             | role_name        | 
+-----------------------+------------------+
|      1                | Admin            |
|      2                | Manager          |
|      3                | Marketing Persion|
|      4                | Employee         |
+-----------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Try the solution i have mentioned in the below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585977/how-can-i-set-data-from-database-in-check-box-using-form-in-zend-framework-1-11/32600201#32600201

Comment: but how can i set up check box in form

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code.

```
class YourForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {

       $DBCnt = getCountofRowsFromDB();

       for($i = 0; $i <= $DBCnt; $i++){
           $checkBoxes[] = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('checkBox_' . $i);//THIS IS WHERE YOU CREATE AND SET THE CHECKBOXES
       }
       $this->addElements($checkBoxes); //THIS IS WHERE YOU ADD THE CHECKBOXES TO THE FORM
  }
}
```

Comment: i declare code in zend form. and it is define error... i ask you what you declare code in zend form.

Comment: my question is that How can i declare a list of check boxes in view using form from read data from role_master database.
Means that developer declare one add element of check box in form named checkbox
Then read the value form Role master and then display in view like i set the image in my question portion and when i submit then i want the value of which i selected check box.....
See my questions again..  above you can understand easily..
Now my questions to you 
What you declared code in form in you side...